# Uploading a file via requests.put in python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying convert the following curl command to python code using requests module.

```
curl -v -X PUT -T video_file.mp4 https://my-app-domain.com
```

Already tried some ways like below but still not working.

```
with open(mp4_file_path, 'rb') as finput:
     response = requests.put('https://my-app-domain.com', data=finput)
```

Can someone please show me how to write it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/), data can accept "dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like object."

This should work:

```
with open(mp4_file_path, 'rb') as finput:
    response = requests.put('https://my-app-domain.com', data=finput.read())
```